# Empty Excel file with a huge size

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that is 70Mb.
It's just a simple table, with bunch of basic formulas.
I've tried deleting all the formulas and deleting everything from that tab. Still after saving it it's about ~70Mb.
I then duplicated the tab and now it's 140Mb, but as far as I can tell the entire tab is empty, since I did CTRL+A - Delete.

How do I find out what take up space in that tab?

Comment: Can you share the excel file?

Comment: Did you try Open and Repair? Or what about using 7zip to extract the file and see what inside it is large? Or maybe saving it as a different file type and then back?

Comment: You can download it from here https://1drv.ms/x/s!AghzPU2_LHzQy7kM1F1MiAuz8yCUig?e=rkXz6s

Comment: what happens when you delete the tab?  Is there any conditional formatting?  did you hit the delete key or right click and select delete?

Comment: If data is important, first create a backup copy. Now hit CTRL + A to select all cells, go to Home Tab --> Clear --> Clear All. (Or try Clear Formats first) Now save and check file size.

Comment: @AlexeyAdamsky the link you shared doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It takes a while to download, is it 140 Mb? there is nothing in the pages? If you need the data just do a copy and pastespecial to another workbook and paste values only then save it. Copy and paste the formula next and check the file sizes as you go, then delete the original.

Comment: Select a row, press "shift + ↓ (down key)", the blank cell may still retain the conditional format or formula.

Comment: Without some screenshots of the data, details of the formulas, size of the table, presence of pivot tables (and caches), details of external connections, and so on, this will not be easy to diagnose. Please edit your post to provide more information.

Comment: @SparedWhisle I think OneDrive is trying to open the file in the browser but it's too big, here is a zip version of that https://1drv.ms/u/s!AghzPU2_LHzQy7kSxSWuSIFIGhGUuA?e=GdLViG

Comment: For anyone asking, I did CTRL+ A -> DEL, and I also check to make sure there is no Conditional Formatting anywhere.

Comment: @FlexYourData the file is empty, not sure how a screenshot would help to diagnose the issue, I also just shared a zip with that file above.

Comment: It's not about the current state but the state prior to that.

Comment: I don't know what the state prior to that is, sorry. I got this file from my friend who is not very good at Excel. So I don't know what exactly he did to cause it. All I know is it had 2 tabs: 1 with a table and formulas and the second one with a graph pointing to the first tab. I've deleted the tab with the graph and cleared everything of the first tab. And when I duplicate that empty tab it doubles the size of the file to 140Mb. You can download the zip above and see for yourself that it appears empty and the first two tabs cause the 140Mb size of the file.

Comment: You did CTRL + A & Del but that deletes only contents, I suggested to clear formats. I downloaded your file and after clearing All Formats, the file size is now just 12 KB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened the Excel file in 7zip and extracted sheet1.xml.

I then opened sheet1.xml in VS Code.

[image]

Unfortunately the file quickly crashes the editor before I can copy any of the data out of it. What I can see though is that there is a *lot* of data in that sheet. I agree that when opening in Excel Read Only mode, the sheet appears empty.

Things I'm able to glean from the screenshot:

There is an attribute dyDescent on each row. [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/f11dfda4-46de-4035-8418-d76b0d3898f1).
Specifically:

> specifies the vertical distance in pixels from the bottom of the cells
> in the current row to the typographical baseline of the cell content
> if, hypothetically, the zoom level for the sheet containing this row
> is 100 percent and the cell has bottom-alignment formatting

Additionally, each row has an `s` attribute that indicates a custom style for columns A through X which in many rows appears to have the value 3.

These two together lead me to believe that

a) There is a custom cell alignment on many cells, Ctrl+A then delete will not remove these cell alignments. You can try to select the whole sheet and then change the cell alignment to the default values through Format Cells

b) There is a custom cell style on many cells. Again, deleting contents will not change this. You can select all cells and change the format to General to see if that will help.

If those don't work, then it's not unreasonable to skip the speculation, revert to an earlier state of the file and make incremental changes until the file size improves.

So, start over with a fresh copy of your friend's file.

To reduce the file size of that fresh copy, try these steps (saving a copy as you go):

1. Remove calculated columns (anything with a formula in it, but particularly VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, SUMIF, MAXIF, COUNTIF etc)
2. Remove pivot tables, pivot charts (these can contain very large pivot caches) and charts (charts with thousands of data points will slow the file down)
3. Remove external connections (see the appropriate button on the data tab)
4. Remove any custom styles on the cells

After doing the above steps, re-introduce the important removed elements one by one , saving as you go and notice how the file size changes with each element reintroduced. The top 2 items listed above are likely to have a significant negative impact on file size.

If you find the re-introduction of one formula or pivot chart is causing a specific issue, start a new question to address that specific issue.

Good luck.

Comment: Ah that's a great fine! I didn't think about the width/height of cells, will see what I can find.